# How do I refer to a person who loves to plan every minute?

Tags: phrases

Not sure how to phrase it exactly. It's the opposite of spontaneous.

Comment: Have you considered using a thesaurus?  It can provide [several](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/spontaneous) valid answers to your question.

Comment: What part of speech are you looking for? (You seem to be looking for an adjective, yet people started suggesting nouns.) Please specify. Also, what is the context? What is the desired connotation? What is the register? What is your example sentence? Lastly, what word would you use in your mother tongue? Which dictionaries have you looked up its translation in? What did they say? Why do their translations not work for you? Please specify all that, otherwise people will have no choice but to post suggestions that you've long rejected.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of *meticulous planner*. But I'm not sure whether this has a positive of a negative connotation. Could be both I think.

Answer (score 0):

How about **time-blocking planner**?

Source: [Plan Out Your Day Productively with the “Time Blocking” Method](http://lifehacker.com/plan-out-your-day-productively-with-the-time-blocking-1666983314).

Answer (score 0):

How about **Deliberate** - think about seriously or discuss?

source: [Deliberate](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/deliberate)

Comment: Hi tbp_09 and welcome to ELU! Please consider adding the definition from the linked source to your answer.